# Galois Theory Problem (Fundamental theorem of Galois)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic$>2$. Let $c\in k$, $c\notin k^2$. Let $F=k(\sqrt{c})$. Let $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{c}$ with $a,b\in k$ and not both $a,b=0$. Ket $E=F(\sqrt{\alpha})$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent.
(1) $E$ is Galois over $k$.

(2) $E=F(\sqrt{\alpha'})$ where $\alpha'=a-b\sqrt{c}$

(3) Either $\alpha\alpha'=a^2-cb^2\in k^2$ or $c\alpha\alpha'\in k^2$.
Show that when these conditions are satisfied, then $E$ is cyclic over $k$ of degree $4$ iff $c\alpha\alpha'\in k^2$.

This is a problem from Serge Lang. I proved 1 is equivalent to 2. But I do not know what to do afterward. Do I have to prove 2 equivalent to 3 by proof by contradiction?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000905/

Answer (score 3):

If you've shown $(1)\Longleftrightarrow(2)$, I'll show $(1)\Longrightarrow(3)$ and leave the converse for you (or you can prove $(3)\Longrightarrow (2)$, whichever suits you better).

Suppose $E$ is Galois over $k$. Then we'll show that $\sqrt{\alpha\alpha'}\in F$. Now, if $f(x)=(x^2-a)^2-cb^2$ is irreducible, then $\sqrt{\alpha'}$ is a conjugate of $\sqrt{\alpha}$, and thus belong to $E=F(\sqrt{\alpha})$ since $E$ is Galois. Thus, we have $\sqrt{\alpha'}=x\sqrt{\alpha}+y$ for some $x,y\in F$. By an easy calculation, we have $2xy\sqrt{\alpha}=\alpha'-x^2\alpha-y^2$. The right-hand side is in $F$, so we have three possible cases: $\sqrt{\alpha}\in F$, $x=0$, or $y=0$. Whatever the case, we see that $\sqrt{\alpha\alpha'}\in F$.

If $f$ is reducible, then either $\sqrt{\alpha\alpha'}\in k$ or $\sqrt{\alpha^2}=\alpha\in k$, which implies $b=0$. Both cases gives us $\sqrt{\alpha\alpha'}\in F$, so we have $$a^2-cb^2=\alpha\alpha'=(s+t\sqrt{c})^2=s^2+t^2c+2st\sqrt{c}$$for some $s,t\in k$. Thus $s=0$ or $t=0$, which implies $c\alpha\alpha'\in k^2$ or $\alpha\alpha'\in k^2$.

Comment: @awllower: You are right! In my haste, I forgot to write it down. I've inserted it, but for convenience, it is $(x^2-a)^2-cb^2$. I believe the characteristic is important in proving the equivalence one of the other equivalences.

Comment: @awllower: I'm not sure why you say there is not a reference to the ground field $k$? I mention it in multiple places (implicitly for some of the coefficients).

Comment: OK. Now I still cannot understand two points: first, why is the statement restricted to characteristic being $> 2$? Second, where did you show that, when the conditions are satisfied, the Galois group is cyclic of degree $4$? Still thanks.

Comment: @awllower: I didn't show that because as stated in Lang, it's not part of the third condition. In fact, reading it, the last sentence only makes sense if it is referencing one one of the three conditions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8009/discussion-between-awllower-and-clayton)

Comment: I deleted some comments to make it seem clearer. Let me ask one more question: is your classification by $f$ being irreducible or not the same as saying that $\alpha\alpha'$ or $c\alpha\alpha'$ is a square, so that your answer is in fact complete? Thanks again!